# Can I just release the top object (iPhone)?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I release the object that's holding a reference to the variable that I need to `release`, is that sufficient? Or must I `release` at every level of the containment hierarchy? I fear that my logic comes from working with a garbage collector for too long.

For instance, I assigned to this property of a `UIPickerView` instance by hand instead of using IB

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UIPickerViewDelegate> delegate
```

Since it's an `assign` property, I can't just `release` the reference after I assign it. When I finally `release` my `UIPickerView` instance, do I need to do this:

```
[singlePicker.delegate release];
[singlePicker release];
```

or is the second line sufficient?

**Also:** Are these `assign` properties the norm, or is that mostly for Interface Builder? I thought that `retain` properties were the normal thing to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are declared `assign` instead of `retain` for a reason - delegates are not owned by their holders and they don't call `release` on them. Otherwise there would be a problem with circular references. You however have to call release on the object you use as the delegate somewhere if you own them.

If delegates were retained, imagine the following situation:

- `a` takes `b` as a delegate, retains `b`
- `b` takes `a` as a delegate, retains `a`

Now you have a circular reference - without ugly cleanup code that explicitly tells them to release their delegates, both of the objects will never be deallocated.

The subject is treated in [Delegation and the Cocoa Application Frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW27):

> Delegating objects do not (and should not) retain their delegates. However, clients of delegating objects (applications, usually) are responsible for ensuring that their delegates are around to receive delegation messages. To do this, they may have to retain the delegate in memory-managed code. This precaution applies equally to data sources, notification observers, and targets of action messages. Note that in a garbage-collection environment, the reference to the delegate is strong because the retain-cycle problem does not apply.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would you mind mentioning briefly why it would be a problem with circular references?

Comment: yes, completely. I never knew why automatic garbage collection was such a big deal. I think I get it now :)